# What is the best way to compare 2 arrays each filled with arrays in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to create two arrays filled with arrays but unsure as to what would be the best way to compare these two arrays.

Attempted to create a quadruple nested loop but that wouldn't really work because when I am comparing the array in the array with the second array in the second array, I want to see if they are the same, despite the order of the contents inside them.

```
For x = 1 To maxRow - 1
    secondCount = 0
    For y = 1 To 7
        tempString = searchArray(x)(y)
        For a = 1 To Worksheets("PART LIST").UsedRange.Rows.count
            For b = 1 To count - 1
            
            Next b
        Next a
    Next y
Next x
```

Comment: Is there any reason you're using jagged arrays (arrays of arrays) in the first place?

Comment: @BigBen Not necessarily, it just made the most sense to me when I was doing it as I am trying to rewrite some old macros I made and cut down the runtime for them.

Comment: Do you want to check if the two jagged arrays contain the same contents if you "flatten" them, regardless of order?

Comment: So basically say my jagged array looks like this

{{ 1, 2, 3}
{2 , 4, 6}}

And my second is 

{{ 2, 1, 4}
{3, 2, 1}}

I want to loop through it so the first array in my first jagged array returns true when searching through the second jagged array it finds the second array inside it since they have the same contents. Sorry if this is a really confusing explanation, I am not a big VBA guy.

Comment: How are you creating the arrays .. Where is the data coming from ?

Comment: Do you have 3 records or 3 milj? Makes a difference in the approach because in the latter its better to calc the sum of the inner array first.

Comment: @CPD1802 The data is coming directly from my excel sheets.

Comment: So are you comparing rows on 2 sheets? If a difference is found how should it be shown ?

Comment: I'm not looking for a difference, I'm looking to see if the rows have the same contents, regardless of how they are arranged. And if it is found, it essentially just writes the row that it was found on in the second sheet.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to compare the contents of two arrays:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    Dim x As Long, b As Boolean, b2 As Boolean, t
    t = Timer
    For x = 1 To 50000
         b = SameContent(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(5, 4, 3, 2, 1))
         b2 = SameContent(Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5), Array(55, 4, 3, 2, 1))
         If x = 1 Then Debug.Print b, b2
    Next x
    Debug.Print Timer - t
End Sub


Function SameContent(arr1, arr2) As Boolean
    Dim ub As Long, lb As Long, v, f() As Long, i As Long, j As Long
    
    lb = LBound(arr1) 'assuming lbounds are the same between arr1 and arr2...
    ub = UBound(arr1)
    If ub = UBound(arr2) Then  'arrays must be the same size
        ReDim f(lb To ub)      ' "matched" flags
        For i = lb To ub
            v = arr1(i)
            For j = lb To ub
                If f(j) = 0 Then 'already matched?
                    If arr2(j) = v Then
                        f(j) = 1
                        GoTo matched
                    End If
                End If
            Next j
            Exit Function
matched:
        Next i
        SameContent = True
    End If
End Function
```